# Validador console

Tags: c#, console

Boa noite, preciso programar um validador de usuário em C# (Possuo visual studio). No estilo console.
Preciso que a partir de uma lista .txt o valor de "id=" na URL seja alterado.

https://www.sitevalidador.com.br/bi5/Paginas/cliente/Login.aspx?id=`idatualnalista`&pc=05

Se possuir uma tal mensagem na página web como por exemplo um "OK", então pegar o valor do id atual e apresentar um log no console dizendo que é valido.

Por exemplo adicionei uma lista possuindo três id's sendo dois deles inválidos

`2446

4452

4445`

Pelo o fato da última id da lista ser a válida, apresentar a mensagem no console:

> VÁLIDA 4445

E por fim, salve todas as ids "válidas" em um .txt no mesmo diretório do .exe.

Muito obrigado!

Espero que tenham entendido, não tenho a  minima ideia de como fazer isto. Se possível, me ajudem, por favor!

Comment: você quer fazer um bot que entre em uma página fornecendo uma url com o id do usuário e pegar a resposta pra dizer se é ou não válido, é isso?

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas vou colocar um exemplo aqui pra você de como ler esse arquivo e pegar exatamente o pedaço que você precisa.

```
public void ReadFile()
{
    string line;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\filelist.txt"))
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("id=", StringComparison.Ordinal), 7).Replace("id=", ""));
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Aí você adapta no seu código e faz suas validações.. isso vai retornar o pedaço do ID da sua URL dentro do arquivo.